# LINQ inner WHERE - inner collection not contains string

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the following collection:

```
ONE
- Banana
- Mango

TWO
- Apple
- Mango

THREE
- Orange
- Pear
```

I want to get only the collection which do not have Mango in it, such as:

```
THREE
- Orange
- Pear
```

The following example returns wrong result:

```
List<Order> list = new List<Order> {
                new Order { Id = 1, Name = "ONE", Items = new List<Items> { new Item { Id = 1, Nama = "Banana" }, new Items { Id = 2, Nama = "Mango" } }},
                new Order { Id = 1, Name = "TWO", Items = new List<Items> { new Item { Id = 1, Nama = "Orange" }, new Items { Id = 2, Nama = "Mango" } }},
                new Order { Id = 1, Name = "THREE", Items = new List<Items> { new Item { Id = 1, Nama = "Pear" }, new Items { Id = 2, Nama = "Chery" } }},
            };

var result = list.Where(x => x.Item.Any(y => y.Nama != "Mango")).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you mean `x.Items.All(y => y.Nama != "Mango")`

Comment: Please answer and I will accept it

Comment: Just to add somethinf Dino, Items, should be called Item. If not it generates confusion, the list of Item should be called items

Comment: Or you can do `!x.Items.Any(... == ...)`. Either way, small typo.

Comment: @nalnpir you are right, it is just an example of my real code, I updated and thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

`Any` will bail out as soon as a "Nama" different from 'Mango' is found which is not what you want.

```
x.Items.All(y => y.Nama != "Mango")
```

Should do it.